# Struct in a struct

Tags: c

Is this usage suitable, and what does it mean?

```
struct Taken
{
int *p;
struct Taken *previous;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Taken *previous;
```

This line declares `previous` to be a pointer to another structure of the same type `Taken` -- this can be used to chain together several such structures, for example, to form a linked list. If you're not familiar with this kind of usage, you should probably read up on pointers and their applications.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably a linked list, but it's not a struct in a struct, it's a pointer to a struct.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the typical data structure for a linked list. A linked list is a data structure that consists of a sequence of data records such that in each record there is a field that contains a reference (i.e., a link) to the next/previous record in the sequence

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Comment: Can you explain a little bit.

Comment: To create a linked list, it is a data structure that consists of a sequence of data records such that in each record there is a field that contains a reference (i.e., a link) to the next/previous record in the sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a suitable usage and what you're looking at is most likely a node in some sort of linked list.

Answer (score 0):

It means that `previous` is a pointer to a `Taken` struct.  Yes, it is valid.

Answer (score 0):

This is the standard element that is used in a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).